# RxJS best way to limit and return response results array

Tags: arrays, http, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm using Angular 2's http service to get some data, the API returns 'n' number of results, but I only want to handle 'x' amount.

Considering that I don't have access to the API's endpoints (in order to create limit or findOne kind of methods) I'm trying the figure out the best way to handle the number of results that will be returned to the component that calls my HomeService's "loadLatest" method.

With this particular example, the response is an object that looks something like this:

```
{
 success: true,
 data: [Object, Object, Object],
 user: 'testUser'
}
```

I'm only interested in the data array (say, get only the first two objects it contains).

If I wanted to get a single result I could do something like this:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const URL = 'http://exampleapi.com/example';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
 constructor(private _http: Http){}

 loadLatest() {
  return this._http.get(URL)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(({data}) => data[0]);
 }
}
```

And it works (which doesn't necessarily mean it's actually ok)... However, I know there's got to be a better way to return, for instance, the first two objects within the data array in the response's object. Or the first three, or four... Or however many I want.

I read about the "take" method, however I do not believe it would actually work in this case...

This is where I'm subscribing to it and using the service within my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
 selector: 'home',
 templateUrl: './home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 // I used this typing because I originally only wanted a single item
 // This might have to change
 items: Observable<Object>

 constructor(private homeService: HomeService){}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.homeService.loadLatest()
  .subscribe(result => this.items = result);
 }
}
```

As you can see, I want for the result to be an array with two objects, which I assign to this.items, so that I can iterate over these two objects using angular's *ngFor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the person who downvoted my question would like to elaborate as to why he/she did so... Not sure if my question came across the right way. I'm really wondering if there is a specific reactive method to have the above accomplished and as I commented on Puigcerber's answer, I'm also wondering if the map method with the slice method is the most permormant approach. But a downvote with no explanation on a legitimate question... Really?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `slice` method in the data array.

```
loadLatest() {
  return this._http.get(URL)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(({data}) => data.slice(0,2));
}
```

Comment: I still get confused between Array's "map" method and RxJS' map. On the Array's map, it always goes into each one of the items that the array you're iterating through contains, you "can't" break out of the iteration. I think that's what confused me about this. I'm guessing on this case I can simply use slice inside of the map method and it will only "go in" once and perform the operation? What I'm trying to say is that it won't go in 4 or 5 or 6... times (the length of items inside the "{data}" array) and perform the same slice action repeteadly, yeah? Not sure if I'm making myself clear...

Comment: I originally thought about this approach you propose as well, however, I'm not sure if this is performant or not. Because I don't really understand exactly how Observables and RxJS work... Not sure if this in fact is "light" and performant or if there's a specific method or pattern to achieve this. Also, really not saying it isn't, I'm genuinely wondering.

Comment: They will be called only once every time someone subscribes to the observable. The first `map` gets the `response` object and transform it into a JSON object that is what the second `map` gets, but you only want the data property so you are using object destructuring to get the data array and `slice` it to return just the portion you need.

Comment: No, I mean, that part I understand, I was able to implement it with no problem. I believe it was simply a matter of me not fully understanding just how `map` really worked, I have read the documentation and I now get it. It's not as the map function I'm used to working with, it just shares the same name. I still wonder if there's a reactive specific method for this, but I believe this works just fine with no major inconveniences. Really, if anything, I feel foolish for not thinking this through before posting the question... Guess I "deserve" the downvote, ha! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It was not me who down-voted it so I'm making it right for you with a +1, haha. The RxJS `map` works on the stream of events and in this case, as the Http observable only emits one value, you can think of it as an array of one element. Maybe this analogy helps you a bit more.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely does! Thanks a lot! And yeah, I figured it wasn't you, but thanks a lot for helping out with the upvote and for your help in general!

Comment: @Puigcerber If I use .reverse() before the slice(), would this always give me the 2 most recent items. And then reverse() again to return the correct order. I am trying to limit my array length but only for the most recent items? Thanks...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson you could use slice with a negative index as `data.slice(-2)`.